# How To Copy Range of Last Row of Data and Paste into Row below It

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to to create a macro to get the last row of data on my sheet & copy/paste it into the row before it.
I need it to pick up the data in Columns B-N.
I am able to do it for just column B using the below code but i cant figure out the syntax to get it do do it for column B-N - can someone help?

```
Sub copylastrow()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Copy
Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the column that you're aiming to find the last row with data, B or N? and are you pasting special values?

Comment: Thank - I declared the worksheet b/c theres about 40 other sheets i will need the identical process for - & I am aiming to copy the last row of data( in my case row 46) into row 47 with the formulas - which is why i didnt transfer them - any recommendations?

Comment: Do you know all the sheets' names? are all the sheets in the same workbook? is it always row 46?

Comment: I do know all the names, it will always be the last row in the data set being copied to the next row(so this month is 46->47, next month will be 47->48, etc), and yes they are all in the same workbook. But i actually adjusted the code you gave me to carry the formulas & solved everything i needed to already - i greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Awesome. If the code helped, consider marking the answer so others may find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments in the code:

- Define the source sheet (no need to activate it)
- Find the last row in an specific column
- Set the source range according to columns and last row
- Transfer values without copying them is faster

Assumptions:

- Column B is the reference to get the last row
- You're just pasting values

Read the comments and adjust the code to fit your needs.

**Code**

```
Public Sub CopyLastRow()
    
    ' Define the source sheet (no need to activate it)
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Find the last row in an specific column
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Range("B" & sourceSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Set the source range according to columns and last row
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("B" & lastRow & ":N" & lastRow)
    
    ' Transfer values without copying them is faster
    sourceRange.Offset(1).Value = sourceRange.Value

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works